# I prefer doing ... vs I prefer to do

Tags: grammar, usage

A: Do you want me to help you?

B: I **prefer doing** this on my own.

or

B: I **prefer to do** this on my own.

Can **I prefer doing ...** be used interchangeably with **I prefer to do ...**?

What's the difference?

Comment: Hello Marcin,  Your exact question has been asked before, so instead of writing an answer you can see the answers that were given before.  This should answer your question.  Let me know if the answers there are not clear for you.

Comment: I have seen many posts on this topic, but in my grammar book, it is written that we use the -ing forms when expressing a general preference. We use the infinitive, however, when expressing a preference for a specific moment. That's why in the example I provided, the form "I prefer to do..." is the only correct one.

I wanted to hear your opinions on this because I don't fully agree with the statement in the book. However, posts on this forum indicate that these forms can be used interchangeably, but I'm not entirely sure. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, but I think that aspect has already been answered, in the linked question: the difference is at most subtle and nuanced. Both are "correct",  but for the reasons given elsewhere, in particular contexts one or the other might be better.

Comment: So, my grammar book is right and I shouldn't use "I prefer doing this on my own" in my example?

Comment: How can you read "Both are correct" as "I shouldn't use 'prefer doing'" ?  Let me repeat.  Both are correct.  In some contexts you would be more likely to use "I prefer doing" and in some contexts "I prefer to do".

Comment: A: Do you want to watch TV now?
B: I prefer to listen to some music.
vs
B: I prefer listening to some music.

Can I use both with no difference in meaning?

Comment: 'In some contexts you would be more likely to use "I prefer doing" and in some contexts "I prefer to do"'  In that context you should use a conditional "I'd prefer" and  "to watch".

Answer (score 0):

*Prefer to do & Prefer doing*

You can use 'prefer to (do)' or 'prefer -ing' to say what you prefer in general:

> I don't like cities. I prefer to live in the country.

> I prefer living in the country.

The differences in structure after prefer:

I **`prefer doing`** something **`to doing`** something else.

I **`prefer to do`** something **`rather than (do)`** something else.

> Look at these examples:

I **`prefer driving`** to travelling by train.

I **`prefer to`** drive **`rather than`** travel by train.

> If we want to check your sentences, we can look at them like this:

I **`prefer doing`** this on my own **`to doing this with you.`**

I **`prefer to do`** this on my own **`rather than do this with you.`**